# Import top level file inside subdirectory

Tags: python

I have the following structure in my Python project:

```
project
├── subdir
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script_to_run.py
├── __init__.py
└── functions.py
```

In `script_to_run.py` file, I want to import a function from top-level `functions.py` file as

```
from functions import function_to_import
```

When I try to run the script from either root directory (`project`) or its subdirectory (`subdir`), I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
```

How do I import it then?

I've seen several approaches, including messing with your `sys.path` or installing your local package through `pip`, but that seems like too much work for something this simple, right?

Comment: Don't put a script inside a package; keep it outside the package.

Comment: @9769953 what if I want to have it separated from files in top-level directory? I have several scripts that I want to keep inside `subdir` (and also scripts that I want to keep inside `another_subdir` and so on), because I don't want to clutter top-level directory with many scripts

Comment: Create a separate `scripts` directory, and put all your scripts in there.

Answer (score 0):

Python packages are a great thing, but come at a cost: you cannot directly run a file lying deep in the package.

If the file is imported from the package, the correct way would be:

```
from ..functions import function_to_import
```

If the file is intended to be launched as a top level script, it should not be in the package. If you really want to go that way, the solution is to add the `project` directory to `sys.path` and use:

```
from functions import function_to_import
```

but it is an anti-pattern... You have been warned...